# Generate combined code coverage report from slather for iPhone & iPad build

Tags: ios, code-coverage

I am using slather 2.4 to generate Code coverage reports for my iOS code base. There are so many scenarios in code where code works differently specific to device i.e iPhone or iPad.

When I run test build for iPhone it gives different percentage & for iPad it gives different percentage. I just wanted to check if there is any way to club report for these two different builds & get accurate code coverage. Or any way so that it considers both options in code while generating single code coverage report.

Comment: I do not believe Slather can do this. However, if you are ok with a hosted solution: Codecov can merge reports: https://docs.codecov.io/docs/merging-reports and 
http://docs.codecov.io/docs/flags to learn more.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your inputs. Will explore more that.
My main requirement is to put all these correct reports on Jenkins for tracing proper code coverage.